# How i draw this Speech Bubble in compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

[desing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtRNh.png)I try with canvas but can't do like this.

Who create speech bubbles with tails, making them look more like messages in a chat interface. Adjustments such as colors, padding, and tail alignment can be made as per your design requirements.

[i want do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XLJa.png)

Comment: Please change your text to make it clearer. From what you wrote it is not clear what you are asking for

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If an answer resolved your question, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at official Jetpack Compose Sample App "[JetChat](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/main/Jetchat)". It is open-source and also implements some sort of chat bubbles.

Their implementation can be found under the [Conversation.kt](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetchat/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/jetchat/conversation/Conversation.kt#L414) file:

```
private val ChatBubbleShape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp, 20.dp, 20.dp, 20.dp)

@Composable
fun ChatItemBubble(
    message: Message,
    isUserMe: Boolean,
    authorClicked: (String) -> Unit
) {

    val backgroundBubbleColor = if (isUserMe) {
        MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
    } else {
        MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surfaceVariant
    }

    Column {
        Surface(
            color = backgroundBubbleColor,
            shape = ChatBubbleShape
        ) {
            ClickableMessage(
                message = message,
                isUserMe = isUserMe,
                authorClicked = authorClicked
            )
        }
         
        // ...
    }
}
```

We can see that they achieve the bubble shape by creating a `Surface` and setting a `shape` parameter. As a shape, they use a modified [`RoundedCornerShape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/shape/RoundedCornerShape). You can adjust that to your needs or create an own shape that extends the [`Shape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Shape) interface as described [here](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/cookbook/how_to_create_custom_shape/):

```
class MyCustomShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(size: Size, density: Density): Outline {
        val path = Path().apply {
            moveTo(size.width / 2f, 0f)  // position pencil on top center
            lineTo(size.width, size.height)  // draw line to bottom right
            lineTo(0f, size.height)  // draw line to bottom left
            close()  // close the path - draws a line to the top center
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}
```

Above code will create a triangle shape that you then could assign to a `Surface`. You will have to experiment with `moveTo`, `lineTo`, and `close` in order to achieve the desired shape.